# akka non-blocking BoundedMailbox

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to find a non-blocking way to use akka actors with BoundedMailbox.  It should drop messages when actor's mailbox is full.  Can I achieve it by just setting pushTimeOut to 0?  Is there any drawback or things to notice with this approach?

Comment: Drop new incoming messages or drop older ones?

Comment: drop new incoming messages

Comment: Setting pushTimeout to 0 will certainly give you a low wait time use of a bounded mailbox, but it will not be non-blocking. The bounded mailbox uses a LinkedBlockingQueue as its queue implementation. When it puts messages on the queue, it uses `offer` that takes the pushTimeout as an input. Even if its 0 you still incur the overhead of acquiring the lock necessary for adding the item so it's not a non blocking solution

Comment: @cmbaxter, thank you for the answer.  So, what's the best way to use bounded non-blocking mailbox for actors?

Comment: I don't think you can combine a bounded mailbox with non-blocking.  In order to be properly (thread safe) bounded, synchronization is needed.  I would think if a good bounded and non-blocking impl was possible, the akka guys would have made one.  I guess you need to decide which is more important to you; having a bounded mailbox or having a very high throughput mailbox because I believe those two concepts are somewhat exclusive.  You may want to give this post a read and see if another kind of approach might be the solution: http://letitcrash.com/post/28901663062/throttling-messages-in-akka-2

Comment: It may be little old but how about switching context of an Actor? When it's mailbox gets saturated it switched to i.e. `processing` state and switch back when comfortable?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you set the pushTimeOut to 0 new messages will be dropped if the mailbox is full. The dropped messages will be sent to the special [dead letters actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/general/message-delivery-guarantees.html#deadletters).